# Jquery-Ajax auto slider with auto updating images

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am using jquery, ajax and php to implement a bunch of scrolling images. It should be an auto scroller of images and the images list is loading from database. I need to update the images showing in scroller in 5 seconds. I implemented it using jquery's jCarousel slider.

But now i need to update the images without interrupting the scrolling.

My head is heating up and I cant find out a logic for it. Any Ideas?

Comment: use javascript setTimeInterval method to get images after certain interval of time .

Comment: I used jquery.get function to retrieve data from the file. But i am not getting the updated data if page is not refreshed.

@AshirvadSingh I tried it. But cant proceed by that way in my case ithink.

Since my reputation is 3, I cant post code as answer before 8 hours since my post